# JSP - In If else, else is not considered

Tags: jsp

In the code below, Else is not working...not sure why..also I need to write a code snippet for three login attempts failed. As Else is not working, I am not able to work on it as well, please suggest.

```
<%
    String strusername123 = request.getParameter("username1");
    String strpassword123 = request.getParameter("password1");    

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, password);

    statement = connection.createStatement();

    rs1 = statement.executeQuery("SELECT USERNAME5, PASSWORD, USERID FROM
        USERS WHERE USERNAME5='" + request.getParameter("username1") + "'
        and PASSWORD='" + request.getParameter("password1") + "'");

    while (rs1.next()) 
    {           
        if (stradmin.equals(rs1.getString("USERNAME5")))
        {
            session.setAttribute("USERID1",rs1.getString("USERID"));
            RequestDispatcher dd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Adminhome.jsp");
            dd.forward(request, response);
        }
        if ((strusername123.equals(rs1.getString("USERNAME5")) &&
                 strpassword123.equals(rs1.getString("PASSWORD")))) 
        {
            session.setAttribute("USERNAME6", strusername123);
            session.setAttribute("USERID",rs1.getString("USERID"));
            response.sendRedirect("HomePage.jsp");
        } 
        else 
        {        
            out.println("Wrong Password dude");
        }
    }       
    rs1.close();
%>
```

Comment: Grmph... That's the reason why good practices recommend **NOT** to put a lot of Java code in JSP scriptlets! It is easier to write and test in plain Java. BTW, you are forwarding to another JSP in the middle of the loop, keeping the connection and the cursor opened. Put that code in a HttpServlet, or even better create an auxilliary class that controls a username and password and gives in return a userid and an boolean saying whether user should have admin permissions. But please stop writing spaghetti code...

Comment: ok thanks a lot Serge....will write in Java now, do you think by writing it in Java will resolve my problem?

Comment: Honestly, it won't be enough to solve the problem, but it will be much easier to test and debug and finally fix it... Remember the Keep It Stupidly Simple rule : one java class should be in charge of one simple task: easier to write and test. Good luck with your further codings :-)

Comment: While you're rewriting this code in the proper place: Read about [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) and prepared statements. It's trivial to log in as any user with the password `whatever' OR '1'='1`. (plus: One does not have plain text passwords in the database, ever)

Comment: At a glance, doesn't the 2nd `if` need to be an `else if`?

Comment: Runningviolent, i tried that as well still it did not work out, hence posted it in stackoverflow :)

Comment: After some more analysis got the answer why it was not working...I was writing while, instead of while I could have used if, because any ways condition of verifying username and password is anyways getting covered in Select query only thing I need to check is if it matches or not through IF condition. And anyways I have written it in Servlet and that solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help!!!.